# How to Set iFrame Width Height the same for all images

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox-2

First I am using fancyBox version: 2.1.5  and jquery-1.11.3.js on a ASP.NET page.

What I am trying to do is to set the width and Height of the iframe fixed for all the image. Right now the frame grows or shrink to adapt to the images size, I don't like that. To fit images with different Width/Height ratio it must increase or decrease the inside paddings but never touch the frame dimension. I don't want to see scrollbars, images must be fitted inside the content region.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
$("#fit").fancybox({
    width       : 600,
    height      : 600,
    scrolling: "no",
    aspectRatio:true,
    fitToView   : false,
    autoSize    : false
});
```